# Comment submission & navigation redirects to default language

Tags: comments, pagination, redirect, forms, multi-language

I'm using **qTranslate** for *multi-language* & **wp-commentnavi** for *comment navigation*. The style of my base permalinks are like so:

```
site.com/     -> for default language
site.com/en/  -> for other language
```

I need help in regards to the following as they keep **redirecting to the default language**:

**1. Comment submission**

How do I hack this? I want the current language to be displayed after submission.

I found this proposed solution:

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2631&p=9037#p8759

..but the problem with that is that **it doesn't direct to the right comment page if there's pagination for the comments**, ie. it directs to the first comment page instead of the last page where the new comment is.

**2. Next/Prev comment page links**

It seems that wp-commentnavi uses `next_comments_link()` & `previous_comments_link()` for the Next/Previous comment page links respectively. For the rest of the links *(eg. pages, first, & last)* I can use the `qtrans_convertURL()` function to direct them to the current language. But I don't know how I could hard code the links for the two former ones, ie. next/previous. Anyone knows?

**3. Comment Link**

I have a link in each comment to the comment link using `get_comment_link()`. Something like so:

```
qtrans_convertURL( esc_url( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) ) )
```

For **comment pages two & above**, the links work fine, in that they direct to the correct language. But **for links that are on page 1**, although the permalinks are correct, but once opened they get redirected to the default language.

For example, in page 1, one comment have a link like so:

> site.com/**en**/post-type/post-name/**comment-page-1**/#comment-2

When opened, it redirects to:

> site.com/post-type/post-name/#comment-2

It seems that anything with ***comment-page-1*** is redirected to a shorter permalink, ie. it got rid of the comment page permalink, but the problem is that it also got rid of the language permalink.

How do I maintain the current language?

Anyone could help? Cheers in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution to my problems. Here's what I did...

> ***Note:***
>   *This is considering the posts, thus comments, are under the '**Article**' post-type, which thus create the permalink such as this: **site.com/article/post-name/#comments**.*
>   *Adjustments should be made for other uses.*

To fix problem #1 & #3:

```
if ( !is_admin() )
    add_filter('get_comment_link', 'my_comment_post_redirect');

function my_comment_post_redirect($location){

    // Retrieve the URL based on current language up to the post-type ('article')
    $currUrl = preg_replace('/(.*article\/).*/', '$1', $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

    // Retrieve the URL from the post name to the location of the comment
    // (ie. comment page & number/ID)
    $cmntPage = preg_replace('/.*article\/(.*)/', '$1', $location);

    // Comment page #1 has special redirection, thus...
    $cmntPageNum    = preg_replace('/.*comment-page-(.*)\/.*/', '$1', $cmntPage);
    // If on first comment page...
    if ($cmntPageNum == 1) {
        // ...then get rid of comment page from permalink
        $cmntPage = preg_replace('/(.*)comment-page-.*\/(.*)/', '$1$2', $cmntPage);
    }

    return $currUrl.$cmntPage;
}
```

> **UPDATED:** The above code will also affect *comment links* in the **back-end** so I added `if ( !is_admin() )` at the top to prevent it from happening.

For problem #2, I created a function for each link (next & previous):

```
function def_get_next_comments_link($label, $max) {
    // Get the complete code generated by the function
    // (which includes the <a> tag)
    $navLink = get_next_comments_link($label, $max);
    // Retrieve the base URL up to the post-type 'article'
    $baseUrl = preg_replace('/.*(http:.*article\/).*/', '$1', $navLink);
    // Replace the base URL with the one for the current language
    return str_replace($baseUrl, qtrans_convertURL($baseUrl), $navLink);
}

function def_get_previous_comments_link($label) {
    // Get the complete code generated by the function
    // (which includes the <a> tag)
    $navLink = get_previous_comments_link($label);
    // Retrieve the base URL up to the post-type 'article'
    $baseUrl = preg_replace('/.*(http:.*article\/).*/', '$1', $navLink);
    // Replace the base URL with the one for the current language
    return str_replace($baseUrl, qtrans_convertURL($baseUrl), $navLink);
}
```

Then I just called the functions where the links are.

This worked for me. :)